# Adding L293D motor shield to Breadboard

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, arduino-motor-shield, l293d

Anyone knows how to attach the l293D motor driver shield on a breadboard?

I need to put the shield on top of a breadboard and then use an Atmega328P as the main way of controlling it.
Than you :)

Comment: If the shield doesn't fit on the breadboard you need to use female to male jumper cables to connect it.

Comment: why do you want to do this? ... plug the shield onto the arduino instead

Comment: you can't put uno shield on breadboard

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledging that it is not exactly the answer to your question, the folks at Adafruit have written an excellent [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-15-dc-motor-reversing/overview) on breadboarding the raw [L293D *chip*](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf). Which may be a more compact option for you?

Your question asks how to attach an L293D shield to a breadboard, and as @Juraj said in the comments, you can't do this easily directly. As @Jsotola mentioned, a UNO format shield is designed to connect directly to a uno, not to breadboard.

On a UNO format shield the pin alignment on the 18 pin (10+8) header sider of the shield (the digital pins) is not a comfortable fit into breadboard hole spacing (the shorter 14 pin side does align OK with breadboard). To make matters worse a UNO shield is wider than the available rows on a single standard breadboard. However, if you're willing to use more force and bend a few pins on the shield (**not recommended**) you can make this work using two breadboards side by side. The photo shows one possibility.
[image: Fitting a UNO shield onto breadboard]

A **better solution** as mentioned by @ChrisL in the comments might be to use [dupont connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179179/what-is-the-official-name-for-these-jumper-wires) to connect the shield pins as needed (e.g. to a non-UNO format arduino).
[image: Dupont connector]

There are different versions and clones of the L293D shield in circulation. I think most of these are based on the (now obsolete) Adafruit open source [version 1](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield). In any case you'll need to refer to the datasheet for the version you're using and be sure to connect every pin required from the shield to the arduino using the dupont connectors.

There are plenty of tutorials available regarding using the L293D shield, one example is at [Last Minute Engineers](https://lastminuteengineers.com/l293d-motor-driver-shield-arduino-tutorial/)